# Calculation with Jpanel.getWidth() not working

Tags: java

*Note: I couldn't find an appropriate title for this question...*

The `class MyPanel` sets up a `JPanel` with a custom drawing on it.  In order to fit the drawing to the actual size of the `JPanel` which is set in another `class`, I need to calculate the ratio of the `JPanels` width or height and an `int scale`.
I need the decimal part of `ratio` because depending on it being < / > 0.5 I want to treat results differently.

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    public  void setUp(int px, int py, int width, int height){
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        this.setBounds(px, py, width, height);
    }

    int scale = 35;

    public int plusX(){
        double ratio = this.getHeight()/scale;
        long integer;
        double fractional;
        int plusX = 0; 

        integer = (long) ratio; 
        fractional = ratio - integer; 
        if (fractional > 0.5){
            plusX = (int) (scale*fractional);   
        }
        if (fractional < 0.5 ){
            plusX = (int) (-scale*fractional); 
        }
        System.out.println("ratio: "+ratio+ " integer: "+integer+" fractional: "+fractional+" plusX: "+plusX);
        return plusX;
    }
}
```

With the output for `width = 1254, height = 648` and `scale = 35` resulting in:

```
ratio: 18.0 integer: 18 fractional: 0.0 plusX: 0
```

But 18 is just wrong, leading up to `fractional = 0.0`.
`scale*ratio` should result in `height` (thus being for the example: `35*18.51=648` with `fractional = 0.51`).

No matter which value i choose for scale, ratio always remains exact .0   .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As perthe [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getHeight--), `getHeight()` gives an `int`. `scale` is also an `int`. In Java, dividing 2 ints gets youan `int`, thus `ratio` becomes `18`.

To fix this, declare scale as double, since thag would yield a floating point number, which is what you are after.

Comment: So obvious I didn't think of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Both scale, and the return value of getHeight() are integers, so even though your ratio variable is initialized as a double, you are dividing two integers which means it will only give you a whole number as an answer. You need to make sure to cast one (or both) values to a double so that you will get the correct answer which should help you with the rest of your calculations.

Example:

```
double ratio = (double) this.getHeight() / scale;
```